# System limit for number of file watchers reached, but I can't use sudo to fix it

Tags: react-native

I have looked around for a solution for this issue, but I do not have admin permissions so I cannot increase the limit of file watchers. I also have a very small project, so I don't understand how it can reach the limit. Does anyone know any fixes that don't involve admin permissions?

The entire error I got was:

```
Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/ludkl571/Documents/TDDC73/test/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-tools/node_modules/chalk'
    at FSWatcher.start (internal/fs/watchers.js:210:26)
    at Object.watch (fs.js:1444:11)
    at NodeWatcher.watchdir (/home/ludkl571/Documents/TDDC73/test/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:159:22)
    at Walker.<anonymous> (/home/ludkl571/Documents/TDDC73/test/node_modules/sane/src/common.js:109:31)
    at Walker.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at /home/ludkl571/Documents/TDDC73/test/node_modules/walker/lib/walker.js:69:16
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:156:23) {
  errno: -28,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'ENOSPC',
  path: '/home/ludkl571/Documents/TDDC73/test/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-tools/node_modules/chalk',
  filename: '/home/ludkl571/Documents/TDDC73/test/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-tools/node_modules/chalk'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288  try this command

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).